# What is google chrome's debug variable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In the google chrome console. I can't find anything by google-ing for it, as I don't know what to search for without getting every other debugging tool in the world and his dog.

If I do `debug.toString()` I get `function debug(fn) { [Command Line API] }` but if I do `window.debug` I get `undefined`.

What is the `debug` function I see in the google chrome console?

Comment: I believe it stops execution at that point in the code.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#debugfunction

Comment: @JoachimRohde this is great - and https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#monitorfunction too!

Answer (score 0):

Use `console.log("");` for see data in google chrome console.